# Setting X-Axis format dynamically from columnvalue

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

I´m using the deneb visual for a bar chart. The datastream comes from a switch-measure (the data provided can be percentage oder whole numbers).

Since the I m using a switch measure, PBI formats dont work, so I m tying to format the barchart X-axis dynamically by a provided column (Format_Verteilung), which contains the format.

columnname: "Format_Verteilung"
value: ".0%"

I have tried different approaches, but they don't work:

1.
"axis":{"format":{"expr":"data('dataset')[0].Format_Verteilung"}}

2.
"axis":{"format":{"field":"Format_Verteilung"}}

3.
"axis":{"format":"datum.Format_Verteilung"}

samplecode, formating y-axis:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 0.1, "myformat":".0%"}, {"a": "B", "b": 0.3, "myformat":".0%"}, {"a": "C", "b": 0.2, "myformat":".0%"},
      {"a": "D", "b": 0.1, "myformat":".0%"}, {"a": "E", "b": 0.4, "myformat":".0%"}, {"a": "F", "b": 0.9, "myformat":".0%"},
      {"a": "G", "b": 0.2, "myformat":".0%"}, {"a": "H", "b": 0.7, "myformat":".0%"}, {"a": "I", "b": 0.7, "myformat":".0%"}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative","axis":{"format":{"field":"myformat"}}}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 0.1, "myformat": ".0%"},
      {"a": "B", "b": 0.3, "myformat": ".0%"},
      {"a": "C", "b": 0.2, "myformat": ".0%"},
      {"a": "D", "b": 0.1, "myformat": ".0%"},
      {"a": "E", "b": 0.4, "myformat": ".0%"},
      {"a": "F", "b": 0.9, "myformat": ".0%"},
      {"a": "G", "b": 0.2, "myformat": ".0%"},
      {"a": "H", "b": 0.7, "myformat": ".0%"},
      {"a": "I", "b": 0.7, "myformat": ".0%"}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
    "y": {
      "field": "b",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"labelExpr": "format(datum.label,data('source_0')[0]['myformat'])"}
    }
  }
}
```